# Кэширование сообщений в мессенджере

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, кэширование

Делаю свой мессенджер в целях самообучение, сделал рабочий прототип с базовыми возможностями. Далее встал вопрос о экономии трафика и кэшировании сообщений пользователей.

Клиент получает сообщения через REST API с тремя параметрами:

 1. Идентификтор пользователя
 2. Начало промежутка сообщений в количестве
 3. Конец промежутка сообщений в количестве
Например: mysite.com/messages?user=vasya@mail.com&from=0&to=50
Значит, что я хочу получить 50 последних сообщений с переписки с пользователем "vasya@mail.com"

Отсюда выплывает три вопроса:
 1. Какие есть способы кэширования данных такого типа?
 2. Как потом определить надо ли мне скачивать сообщения с сервера, либо же брать из кэша (SQLite БД)?
 3. Правильный ли я подход использую выкачивая сообщения из REST API, либо же можно как то по другому, так, что бы удобней было кэшировать?
Спасибо.

Comment: всегда записывай в бд, потом читай и выводи на вью. При повторном запросе можешь проверить время последнего сообщения, если время изменилось то даные изменились и в бд нужно подкачивать данные снова.

Comment: Насчет правильности, тебе вряд ли кто-то подскажет, ведь Facebook создавался тоже абы как, а вырос в Facebook ) Тут каждый сам решает, что ему правильнее. ПО поводу 1-го вопроса. Ты можешь хранить сообщения на сервере, можешь выкачивать их в телефон, а также, можешь делать так, чтобы во время скачивания программы, внутри нее была маленькая ДБ, типа того же sqLite и в нее пусть хранятся сообщения за тот период который тебе нужно. 2-ой вопрос, собственно у тебя уже внутри самого вопроса ответ. Ты указываешь промежуток времени между смс. Относительно now и сверяй первое полученное сообщение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я советую следующий подход.

1. Сервер назначает каждому сообщению номер из возрастающей последовательности.
2. Клиент при обновлении находит сообщение с наибольшим номером и передает его серверу.
3. Сервер находит все сообщения с большими номерами и возвращает клиенту.

Comment: Спасибо, идея проста и понятна. Просто передавать айдишник последнего сообщения на сервер и он вернет все что больше него.

Answer (score 1):

1. Кеширование в базу данных после получения с сервера
2. Если у сообщений нет функционала редактирования, то можно сравнивать первый пришедший элемент с сервера с элементом из БД. Если они одинаковы - то все грузить из кеша
3. Еще делают следующий образом:

   - Отправляем limit (количество сообщений, которое необходимо загрузить) и offset (с какого элемента необходимо грузить сообщения)
   - Увеличиваем offset на каждом последующем запросе, если нам есть что возвращать.

Например:

- отправили limit: 10, offset: 0 - получили первые 10 элементов
- отправили limit: 10, offset: 10 - получили элементы с 10 по 20